# PSTricks code cannot compile

Tags: pstricks

First: The title is not good; feel free to change it to something appropriate.

**Code**

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-poly,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN
    \calc
  \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\def\sides{6}
\def\sidelength{6}
\def\radius{\calc{\sidelength/(2*sin(pi/\sides))}}
\def\RelAngle{\calc{360/\sides}}
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(-\radius,-\radius)(\radius,\radius)
   \PstPolygon[
     PolyNbSides=\sides,
     unit=3
   ]
%   \multido{\rA=0+\RelAngle,\iA=1+1}{\sides}{%
%     \psRelNode[angle=\rA](A)(B){1}{P\iA}
%   }
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I compile using

```
pdflatex -shell-escape <filename>.tex
```

**Question**

*Why* can the code not compile if the three lines are not outcommented, and *how* do I make the code compilable with three lines not outcommented?

Comment: I get a PostScript error `/undefinedresult in --atan--`, followed by `Operand stack: Alpha 0.0 0.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as written in the documentation `\PstPolygon` uses an own `pspicture` environment. If you have more PSTricks commands then you have to disable this with `PstPicture=false`. However, I don't know what's the meaning of (A) and (B)?

I suppose you want to define the nodes of the the edges which is easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-poly,pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\def\sides{6}
\edef\RelAngle{\numexpr360/\sides}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\providecommand{\PstPolygonNode}{\psdot[dotsize=0.15](1;\INode)}
\PstPolygon[PstPicture=false,PolyNbSides=\sides,unit=3]
%\multido{\rA=0+\RelAngle,\iA=1+1}{\sides}{%
%   \psRelNode[angle=\rA](A)(B){1}{P\iA}}  
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am really way too tired (or at least I hope that is the explanation). I simple copied the code from another example and completely forgot about `A` and `B`. `:(` Thank you for the elegant code, though, Herbert.

Comment: by the way: there is also a `\psHexagon`

Comment: Thank you! How do I specify the coordiates for the center of a polygon?

Comment: it is always (0,0). However, you can use `\rput(x,y){\PstPolygon[..]}`

Comment: Nice! (An idea for the `pst-poly` package: Give the user the option to specify the coordinates for the center of a regular polygon.)

Comment: I'll have a look at it, but it collides with the internal pspicture environment

Answer (score 3):

As PSTricks has not provided us with macros accepting coordinates in `(<algebraic expression>|<algebraic expression>)` to define nodes, so we can abuse `\psparametricplot` here as follows.

```
    \psparametricplot[algebraic,plotpoints=2,showpoints]{0}{0}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}
```

can be used to plot a point at `(\X(0),\Y(0))` where both `\X(t)` and `\Y(t)` are algebraic expressions in `t`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \edef\temporary{round(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
         \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
    \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}


\const{Offset}{pi/4}% 45 degrees in radian for the angular diplacement
\const{Sides}{3}% number of sides
\const{SideLength}{3}% assuming in cm
\const{Radius}{SideLength/(2*sin(pi/Sides))}% 3 digits after the decimal point
\const{TwoPi}{2*pi}
\const[0]{PlotPoints}{Sides+1}

\def\X(#1){\Radius*cos(#1+\Offset)}
\def\Y(#1){\Radius*sin(#1+\Offset)}

\def\Picture{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-\Radius,-\Radius)(\Radius,\Radius)
    \psparametricplot[algebraic,plotpoints=\PlotPoints,showpoints]{0}{\TwoPi}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
    \Picture
\end{document}
```

### Animation

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \edef\temporary{round(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
         \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
    \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}

\def\Picture#1{%
\const{Offset}{#1/180*pi}%
\const{Sides}{5}% number of sides
\const{SideLength}{3}% assuming in cm
\const{Radius}{SideLength/(2*sin(pi/Sides))}% 3 digits after the decimal point
\const{TwoPi}{2*pi}
\const[0]{PlotPoints}{Sides+1}
\def\X(##1){\Radius*cos(##1+\Offset)}
\def\Y(##1){\Radius*sin(##1+\Offset)}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-\Radius,-\Radius)(\Radius,\Radius)
    \psparametricplot[algebraic,plotpoints=\PlotPoints,showpoints]{0}{\TwoPi}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}
    \psparametricplot[algebraic,plotpoints=2,showpoints,linecolor=red]{0}{0}{\X(t)|\Y(t)}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
    \multido{\i=0+10}{36}{\Picture{\i}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice, indeed!